# Every UIAlertController disappear automatically before user responds - since iOS 13

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, ios13

Since I'm using iOS 13, each of my    UIAlertController    shows up for about half a second and disappears instantly before any user action. Any idea ?

As I use    UIAlertController    from different parts of my app, I use an extension that allows me to pop up both from classical views and collectionView (cell, header etc...)

```
public extension UIAlertController {
    func show() {
        let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        vc.view.tintColor = Theme.mainAccentColor
        win.rootViewController = vc
        win.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1
        win.makeKeyAndVisible()
        vc.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And here is an example of this extension use :

```
fileprivate func showMissingAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "blablabla", message: "blablablablabla blabla", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.show()
        alert.view.tintColor = Theme.mainAccentColor
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK, blabla", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("ok, leave")})
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    }
```

And further in my code :

```
showMissingAlert()
```

Before iOS 13, every UIAlert worked fine... Since I moved to iOS 13, and even iOS 13.1, it became a big mess... :(

- Any idea about what could cause this?
- And how to prevent using UIAlert as subliminal message :) ?

Comment: But making a second window in this way was always wrong; now the framework has caught up with you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've got exactly the same problem, and fixed it by holding the window in which the alert is being presented in a strong variable.

You can hold a window for presenting alerts in you AppDelegate, for example, and use it in your UIAlertController extension.

```
//In app delegate
let alertWindow: UIWindow = {
    let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    win.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1
    return win
}()
```

Then, in your extension:

```
public extension UIAlertController {
    func show() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        vc.view.tintColor = Theme.mainAccentColor
        appDelegate.alertWindow.rootViewController = vc
        appDelegate.alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        vc.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

---

You will also need to make sure your alert window is removed from view when your alert is dismissed, otherwise your app will become unresponsive, as all taps will be handled by the (invisible) alert window, that's still on top of everything.
I do this by adding this code to the handlers of all actions in the alert:

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).alertWindow.isHidden = true
```

Comment: This is not going to work well when your app supports scenes in iOS 13.

Comment: Wahou, great ! It works well.
But once closed, none of my buttons, textfields, tabbar or navigation bar are enabled anymore... Did you also have this problem ?

Comment: @Creanomy you will need to make sure the window is removed from the view when the alert view is dismissed. I’ll edit my answer later with how I did it.

Comment: @rmaddy I haven’t worked with scenes so far, what will need to be changed on the code I’ve posted here?

Comment: You'll need to change most of it. The way the window in initialized and the fact that the window will need to be associated with the scene delegate, not the app delegate. The real problem is that you must present the alert from a specific scene and its window which means you really need to know which view controller to show the alert from. And since you need to know that, there's no point to doing any of this extra code at all. Just create and present a `UIAlertController` normally.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueLenziSoares, You've made my day :)
I was already thinking about custom each alert with protocol and delegate as impliedly suggested rmaddy's answer... ans i have more than a dozen of UIAlert in my app. 
In brief terms : you rock ! \o/ \o/ \o/

Comment: @pepsy I'm having the same problem here but in Obj-C (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58148334/uialertcontroller-disappearing-since-ios-13). Do you have a solution for this too? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Reanimation instead of declaring the window variable inside the func, do in in your class, for it not to get destroyed as soon as your func returns. I can take a deeper look on it later if this doesn’t solve it.

Comment: @pepsy I’m not noticing any difference. I must be implementing it wrong. If you have a few minutes any help on my question would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this, but still not working, this will show as global alert?, any help please?

Comment: @user_Dennis_Mostajo are you having the same problem described in the question? The alert appearing for a split second then disappearing? This will present the alert on a window with a window level of (alert)+1, which will probably be the topmost window in your application.

Comment: Adding alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1, it still disappearing automatically :(

Comment: @user_Dennis_Mostajo Are you sure you're holding a strong reference to your alert window somewhere safe? In the link you posted, you're creating it inside your `showAlertGlobally` func.

Comment: @pepsy you right! I did it with strong reference and I did could solve it, take your 10 points man, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution also. It is working form me.

write below method in your class.

```
func presentViewController(alertController: UIAlertController, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                topController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then call it from your code as below

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Discard Photo?",
                                                message: "Your photo will not be attached",
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Keep Photo", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Discard", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
            self.PhotoStack.deletePhoto(at: index)
            self.cameraBtn.isEnabled = true
        })

        self.presentViewController(alertController: alertController)
```

Comment: @Skywalker, My Guess is sometimes you cant find the main window. Check the view controller hierarchy when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [pepsy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965463/pepsy) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58133993/7152892).
If you don't want to care about `alertWindow.isHidden = true stuff`, you can do something like this:

```swift
class AlertHandler {
    private static let alertWindow: UIWindow = {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1
        return window
    }()

    private var alertController: UIAlertController

    init(title: String?,
         message: String?) {
        alertController = UIAlertController(title: title,
                                            message: message,
                                            preferredStyle: .alert)
    }

    func addAction(title: String?,
                   style: UIAlertAction.Style,
                   handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil) {
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: title,
                                   style: style) { action in
                                    handler?(action)
                                    AlertHandler.alertWindow.isHidden = true
        }
        alertController.addAction(action)
    }

    func present() {
        AlertHandler.alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        AlertHandler.alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        AlertHandler.alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController,
                                                             animated: true,
                                                             completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you considered to make `alertController` in `window`, please check your animation or other UI things animated together.

e.g, if you do `self.dismiss(VC)` and `self.present(alertController)` together, it makes problem

Best way to develop is not ignore irregular ui events, but check any other things first which has some problems.