# UIAlertController disappearing since iOS 13

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, uialertcontroller, ios13

I have the following function that pops up a UIAlert which allows the user to update their Haptic Feedback setting:

```
- (void)requestHapticSetting{
    UIWindow *alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    alertWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
    [alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

    if(isHapticOn){
        hapticMessage = @"Haptic feedback is currently\nturned ON.\nPlease update preference.";
    }
    else {
        hapticMessage = @"Haptic feedback is currently\nturned OFF.\nPlease update preference.";
    }

    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Haptic Setting"
                                                                   message:hapticMessage
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* onAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"TURN ON" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                         [self saveHapticSettingOn];
                                                     }];

    UIAlertAction* offAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"TURN OFF" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                          [self saveHapticSettingOff];
                                                      }];
    [alert addAction:offAction];
    [alert addAction:onAction];
    [alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I have used this for a couple of years and it works great.

However, since updating to iOS 13 and updating to the latest Xcode, my alert pops up for less than a second before closing.

What has changed that could be making this happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131996/every-uialertcontroller-disappear-automatically-before-user-responds-since-ios but that's in Swift and its answer isn't going to work properly under iOS 13 when you support scenes.

Comment: Are you using scenes in your app under iOS 13 or did you choose to fully opt out of scenes (which you should not be doing)?

Comment: @rmaddy I'm not entirely sure. I use a game engine that generates an Xcode project. Adding this in the past has always worked until now unfortunately. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What seems to have changed is that on iOS 12 and previous versions your app would hold a strong reference to the window just by calling `[alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];`, in iOS 13 it doesn't anymore.

What's happening is that the only strong reference to your `alertWindow` is in your `requestHapticSetting` func, and as soon as this func returns, the window is destroyed, thus removing your alert from the view.

This might be fixed just by adopting iOS 13 scenes, but I haven't tested that. What I can suggest, which **won't properly work if you are using scenes**, is holding your alert window in a strong variable somewhere in your code, and then using it to present the alert. I'd suggest doing so in a singleton or AppDelegate itself.

```
//AppDelegate.h
...
@property (strong) UIWindow *alertWindow;
....
```

---

```
//AppDelegate.m
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...
    self.alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
    self.alertWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    self.alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
    ...
}
...
```

---

```
//Your class that's presenting the alert
#import "AppDelegate.h"
...
- (void)requestHapticSetting{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)UIApplication.sharedApplication;
    [appDelegate.alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    if(isHapticOn){
        hapticMessage = @"Haptic feedback is currently\nturned ON.\nPlease update preference.";
    } else {
        hapticMessage = @"Haptic feedback is currently\nturned OFF.\nPlease update preference.";
    }

    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Haptic Setting"
                                                               message:hapticMessage
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* onAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"TURN ON" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                      [self saveHapticSettingOn];
                                                      [appDelegate.alertWindow setHidden:YES];
                                                 }];

    UIAlertAction* offAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"TURN OFF" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                      [self saveHapticSettingOff];
                                                      [appDelegate.alertWindow setHidden:YES];
                                                  }];
    [alert addAction:offAction];
    [alert addAction:onAction];
    [appDelegate.alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

---

For Swift code, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131996/every-uialertcontroller-disappear-automatically-before-user-responds-since-ios/58133993#58133993).

Answer (score 1):

I have created a helper class which support new UIWindowScene and iOS 13.X and swift 5.X. You guys can try

https://github.com/emraz/ERAlertController