# Present UIAlertView on window

Tags: ios, windows, uialertcontroller, swift5

There are possibility that, there is custom view over my controller and on which I have to show alert. So I am using below extension to present controllers on window rather than on any UIViewController.

**Extension**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func presentControllerToWindow(){
        let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        win.rootViewController = vc
        win.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1
        win.makeKeyAndVisible()
        vc.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Present AlertController**

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Select Option", preferredStyle: .alert)

alertController.presentControllerToWindow()
```

> **Issue :**

The code is working fine upto swift 4.X but in swift 5.X, alert controller appears and dismissed automatically on the other second.

**GIF:**

1. OpenPicker adds custom view as a subview.
2. On clicking add file, I am presenting alertcontroller.
3. Its automatically dismissed.

[image]

> **Edit :**

I am adding my custom view like below.

```
extension UIView {

    func addToWindow()  {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
        self.frame = window.bounds
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window.windowLevel = window.windowLevel + 1
        window.addSubview(self)
    }
}

let customView = MyCustomView()
customView.addToWindow()
```

Now over this `MyCustomView`, I need to show `UIAlertController`

Comment: You should not touch window, You can find top View controller and directly show alert there.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya what's the problem with window?

Comment: @jalone  No problem  but  it is not good practice - there can be scenarios  like multi-window app- and there is chance to conflict with some native controls of the app - Alert view should be shown from the top most view visible in the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add your `UIViewController` view in **UIApplication keyWindow**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func presentControllerToWindow(){
        let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        win.rootViewController = vc
        win.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1
        win.makeKeyAndVisible()
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(vc.view) //added
        vc.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: iOS 13 introduces new style to present a viewcontroller. To dismiss a controller user can swipe down the controller and it leads the conflicts with the image zoom feature I am using. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: You can avoid this by using `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`.

Comment: @palme, I tried `.fullScreen` but nothing changed. Can you please take a look -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/IudLC.gif

Comment: @dahiya_boy let me search regarding that issue. if anything i found then let you know.

Comment: @dahiya_boy have a look at the `vc.isModalInPresentation = true` property (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/3229894-ismodalinpresentation) also add `#available(iOS 13.0, *)` since this is an iOS 13 feature. However it seems like you are setting the `modalPresentationStyle` for the wrong controller as the way it is displayed in your gif is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the following extension to create an alert.

```
extension UIViewController {
  func showAlert(withTitle title: String?, message: String?) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

It works fine with iOS 13

Comment: Yeah bcz you are adding alert on UIViewController not on window. I have a custom View over controller and my controller and 4 buttons also.

Comment: I understand now. Sorry for the confusion. Is this thread helpful? [Apple](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123792)

Comment: Bro your code not matching my requirement. I have edited my post, you will be more cleared about the scenario.

Comment: Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131996/every-uialertcontroller-disappear-automatically-before-user-responds-since-ios/58133993#58133993)

Comment: Hey, It is working but there is any issue. Now I have to write `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).alertWindow.isHidden = true` redundantly. I mean same extension been called from 100s time in my project and its hard to trace now from where i have to hide alertWindow. Did you know is there any callback on dismiss of alertController so that it could be managed centralized.